# Use same implementation for two services with ASP.NET Dependency Injection

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-1.0

I have a `ServiceLifetime.Scoped` dependency that I only want created once per web request, but it needs to fulfill the request for two services. One of them is an interface that an implementation fulfills, the other is the implementation itself. Right now I'm essentially doing this:

```
public interface IService {}

public class ServiceImplementation : IService {
    public Object ImplementationSpecificState;
}

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {
    services.AddScoped<IService, ServiceImplementation>();
    services.AddScoped<ServiceImplementation>();
}
```

Unfortunately, this is giving me two distinct objects with every web request. One in the code that depends on `ServiceImplementation`, and a different one in the code that depends on `IService`.

How do I make requests for `IService` and `ServiceImplementation` provide the same underlying object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By using the [`implementationFactory`-based extension method](https://github.com/aspnet/DependencyInjection/blob/60ca512beec3fefb4cd377ede009ff96b4848456/src/Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions/ServiceCollectionServiceExtensions.cs#L338), you can dive back into the `IServiceProvider`'s dependency graph to get the implementation when asked for the interface, and you don't even lose compile-time type checking.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {
    services.AddScoped<ServiceImplementation>();
    services.AddScoped<IService>(
        provider => provider.GetService<ServiceImplementation>()
    );
}
```

Fancy.

Comment: Hang on! You answered your own question?!?

Comment: Yeah, it's within the guidelines. I was stuck for about 20 minutes and posted it, then thought about it a bit more and solved it 10 minutes later. I guess I needed a little rubber duck debugging.